Disable a button only during an expensive operation in streamlit

python 3.12.2
streamlit 1.33.0

I have an expensive operation and would like to disable a button to execute it only during the operation. In other words, there is an enabled button. When you press it, it is disabled and the operation starts. When the operation ends, the button is enabled again.
This is the code I tried. The button was not enabled during the operation.
import time

import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as stc

def expensive_process():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 123

def main():
    st.session_state.disabled = False

    text_wait = st.empty()

    but_ph = st.empty()
    but = but_ph.button('calculate', disabled=st.session_state.disabled)

    if but:
        st.session_state.disabled = True
        text_wait.markdown('running...')

        result = expensive_process()

        st.session_state.disable = False
        text_wait.markdown(f'The result was {result}')
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I googled "streamlit disable button after click" and checked first several pages. It wasn't much help. I'd appreciate your thoughts on this matter.

So far, right one it works only change enabled to disabled. However, I'm having problem with make it enable again. For, first problem is u shouldn't use directly st.session_state.disabled=True because when u click button it will rerun app so, u need to put  st.session_state.disabled in a if statement. So, looks like you need to add refresh button to rerun app. As far as I know there is only way that. If there is any other way I would be happy to learn that.
import time 
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as stc

def expensive_process():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 123

def main():
    

if "disabled" in st.session_state:
    
    if st.session_state.disabled == True:
        st.session_state.disabled = False
    else:
        st.session_state.disabled = True

else:
    st.session_state.disabled = False
            
        
    text_wait = st.empty()

    but_ph = st.empty()
    
    but = but_ph.button('calculate', disabled=st.session_state.disabled)

    if but:
        text_wait.markdown('running...')

        result = expensive_process()

        text_wait.markdown(f'The result was {result}')
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

When I add refresh button, it works to make disabled button to enable button.
import time

import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as stc

def expensive_process():
    time.sleep(3)
    return 123

def main():
    
    if "disabled" in st.session_state:
        
        if st.session_state.disabled == True:
            st.session_state.disabled = False
        else:
            st.session_state.disabled = True
    
    else:
        st.session_state.disabled = False
        
    text_wait = st.empty()

    but_ph = st.empty()
    
    but = but_ph.button('calculate', disabled=st.session_state.disabled)
    refresh = st.button('refresh', disabled=False)

    if but:
        text_wait.markdown('running...')

        result = expensive_process()

        text_wait.markdown(f'The result was {result}')
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

